# Using only addition, subtraction and multiplication

Tags: puzzle

I have the numbers 6, 30, 8, 8, 3, 7, 1, 2, and 5. Using only addition, subtraction, and multiplication, can you use those numbers to make 60, 54, and 52?

Comment: Do I have to use all numbers provided?

Comment: And can one only use each number once?

Comment: Can you clarify this question please. Are you saying write three equations using the above numbers using addition, subtraction and multiplication only to give 60, 54 and 52 using each number no more than once across all three equations or using each number exactly once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$6+30+8+8+3+7+1+2\color{red}{-}5=60.$$
$$6+30+8+8\color{red}{-}3+7+1+2\color{red}{-}5=54.$$
$$6+30+8+8\color{red}{-}3+7\color{red}{-}1+2\color{red}{-}5=52.$$

P.S. 
$$30\times 2=60.$$
$$6\times (8+1)=54.$$
$$(8+5)\times (7-3)=52.$$

Comment: oh, my mistake, I didn't mention, you can only use the numbers once. So for instance, if you use 30x2=60, you only have the remaining numbers to make up 54 and 52.

Comment: There's a chance it isn't possilbe. It's for a silly math game on my phone and it's wrecking my brain.

Comment: @Greg at most once or exactly once?

Comment: Yeah you can only use each number once to get all 3 numbers.. like I said, it may not be possible.

Comment: @Greg: I added a bit. How about that?

Comment: ah haha You did it! Thank you!

Comment: @Greg: You are welcome!